# Python Keyboard unable to detect key press when inside Citrix/Amazon Workspace

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, keyboard, keypress

I'm trying to detect two different keys pressed. Below is the code.
This works fine when I run it and press keys on any application in my machine.

```
import keyboard, time

def OnKeypress(startkey='tab', endkey='esc'):
    while True:  # making a inifinte loop
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed(startkey):
                time.sleep(0.25)
                print("%s Key pressed." % startkey)
            elif keyboard.is_pressed(endkey):
                print("%s Key pressed." % endkey)
                break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Done Reading input. Keyboard Interuppt.')
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break

OnKeypress()
```

But when the same code is running when I'm using Citrix application or Amazon Workspaces, this is unable to detect those keys.
Is there any way to improve this code to detect Key presses even when using Citrix or AWS?

I'm using Python 3.6.5 in a Windows 10 machine with Citrix Receiver/Amazon Workspace.